# Texture with UV grid not showing up on 3d object

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm new to this. Learned a lot through tutorials, but now I am stuck at uv mapping thing.

Marked all the seams, it all shows well in UV/Image editor, but when I assign texture with UV grid on the mesh I cant see the grid on 3d object. Texturing is on so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

I tried the same with simple cube and it just doesn't show up. Checked few other tuts for this, but none helped to solve this.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: What is in material setup for the cube? Is there Image Texture node added to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the panel to the right click the material tab. add new material. to the right of "color" their is a tiny button. click that button. now click the button that says image texture and then for the image select the one you are already using on your UV mapping.